# Output mysql_fetch_array without putting it into a variable

Tags: php, mysql

The conventional way of doing this would be

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $row['column'];
```

but I would like to know if it is possible to do something like

```
echo mysql_fetch_array($query)['column'];
```

I tried doing this on my local installation, but I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\www\array.php on line 5
```

This is mainly to reduce the number of lines in my code, as I'm writing a function that places a lot of mysql results into variables, and I don't want to have code that looks like

```
$row = ...
$this->data[] = $row[];
$row = ...
$this->data[] = $row[];
...and so on
```

Comment: That syntax `function()['arraykey']` is called _array dereferencing_, and it is possible in the newly released PHP 5.4, but not in earlier versions.

Comment: Just looked that up, thanks. My easyphp installation is running 5.3.9 :S

Comment: Reducing number of lines does not always equal improved code. You also need to consider the readability of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mysql_fetch_object()` instead:

```
echo mysql_fetch_object($query)->column;
```

You can also use [`mysql_result()`](http://de.php.net/mysql_result) to retrieve a single field from the resultset:

```
echo mysql_result($query, 0, 'column');
```

Both cases are **highly inappropriate** though if you want to access more than a single column per row..

Comment: Well since he's not using it in a loop he probably has only one row anyway. When looping not assigning the row to a variable would just result in very ugly code...